# How to remove port number from an url?

Tags: apache, port, apache-config

I have developed an web application and am trying to run it in Apache server. However, I can not run it without specifying the port number. How can I run the app by browsing `192.168.0.1/project` instead of using `192.168.0.1:9000/project`?

Answer (score 3):

If you run your app on port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) your visitors won't need to type in a port number to access the site.

Comment: actually i have uploaded my app in ftp server. to access the app i need to write the port number. what should i do to remove the port number?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the apache/nginx vhost config.

Comment: actually i am totally new to this kind of stuff like configuring apache/nginx..would you please explain it to me? PLEASE....